Formal proof that $\lim\log(a_n)=-\infty\implies\lim a_n=0$
Full statement:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers. If the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(a_n)$$
exists and diverges negatively (i.e. "equals $-\infty$"), then the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$
exists and equals $0$.

Intuitively, the statement is pretty obvious. However, I couldn't come up with a rigorous proof. This statement can clearly be generalized to different functions than $\log$, but I'm particularly interested in this specific case. Of course, being $\log$ a continuous function, the statement
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(a_n)=-\infty$$
holds, but I'm not sure about the converse.

$\exp$ is a continuous function with $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}e^x=0$.

According to the continuity of the $\exp$ function as mentioned by @peek-a-boo as well as the above-mentioned limit property of the $\exp$ function, we can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\log(a_{n})\right) = 0
\end{align*}

Oh, thanks, don't know how I didn't think of that lol

Strictly speaking this is not the continuity of $\exp$. At least not in the usual sense. For this you'll need to consider the extended real numbers and use that $\exp$ is continuous at $x=-\infty$, but I doubt that's what OP has in mind.

Let $b_n=\log{a_{n}}$, for all positive integers $n$. Then $a_n=e^{b_{n}}$, for all positive integers $n$. By the continuity of the exponential function $x\mapsto e^{x}$, we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{b_{n}}=e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_{n}}=e^{-\infty}=0.$$

Strictly speaking this is not the continuity of $\exp$. At least not in the usual sense. For this you'll need to consider the extended real numbers and use that $\exp$ is continuous at $x=-\infty$, but I doubt that's what OP has in mind.

Strictly speaking, it is the continuity of $e^{x}$ together with its monotonicity.
